# Will the cold water from a faucet be warm if a re-circulation bridge valve is used?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

We are building a new house.  The master bath is the furthest spot from the tankless water heater.  The builder is specifying the WaterQuick Premiere circulation pump with the bridge valve.  It looks like it has a water flow sensor.  So to activate it, it looks like you give the faucet a quick turn on/off on the hot water side.  Which activates the pump and will run until the bridge valve shuts down the flow (meaning the hot water is reaching the bathroom).
My issue with the bridge valve is that now I'm pumping warmed water into the cold side, so if I want to get a drink from the sink while this is running, the water will be almost hot coming from the cold side, right?

I have asked the builder to do a dedicated return from the furthest point and then put the pump on it, with a smart outlet that I can then either time when the pump will run, and/or a button in the bathroom when we walk in.

Am I thinking too much into this? Which would you do in a new build?

Thanks

Comment: A circulation pump on a tankless water heater ?

Comment: Yes.  It's pretty common, in fact more common.  Since a regular water heater can actually heat the copper pipe up a bit.  But in a tankless, when you're done with water it turns the heater off, so water in the pipes start to cool right away.

Comment: So it only circulates left over hot water with out turning on the thankless heater ? Wont the  water cool down after a few hours, or is there a thermostat  that will fire it back up to keep the loop hot ?

Comment: Why is the tankless water heater so far from the point of use? Circulation pump schemes basically defeat the purpose of a tankless, since it’s now a tanked heater.  (The tank being 3/4” x 75’ x 2 pipes or whatever, and it’s going to lose all that heat quickly, so it’s energy wasted).   And I can’t believe you have to *explain to the guy* not to return the tepid water on the cold pipe, how cynical are these people, they’re just selling you stuff for an easy markup? The whole “circulation pump” concept is just kludgey as can be.

Comment: If it is a new build then you can  give the master bath its own, closer, Tankless  WH. NO ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan no the dedicated return would come back and "T" in to the cold side of the water heater.   https://www.contractoraccess.com/wp-content/uploads/Pumps2F70603_HR-3.jpg.           Harper... valid question. The kitchen/laundry are close to the water heater, but the master bedroom is relatively far.  The bridge valve is the most common implementation, especially in a retrofit/post-construction application.  But my thought here is, we are still looking at dirt. Let's do it right.

Comment: I did this using the cold side and needed double check valves  you will have to make sure your pump is large enough to trip the tankless the double check helped to create the pressure drop a dedicated line makes sense the standard pump and bridge setup is for existing systems. In my opinion a point of use electric makes more sense on a tankless system a small unit will fit in the bathroom sink cabinet some are smaller than a bread box.

Comment: Is all this to avoid wasting water down the sink or the shower while waiting for the hot water to arrive? Is the concern the lavatory or the shower?

Comment: @JimStewart yes. It’s a huge waste of water and frankly a decent amount of time.

Comment: Since you are at the looking at dirt stage, a plumber told me he does not put naked PEX under a slab. He uses 1-1/2 inch polybutelene as a pipe chase for 3/4 inch PEX below a slab to the water heater. If that line develops a leak, it can be pulled out and replaced. From there all supply lines are in the attic and walls. I asked him about rats chewing holes in PEX. He said it was a common problem in Dallas, but that there was an insulation that rats find distasteful.

Comment: Is your foundation slab? Rebar or post tension cables?

Comment: Slab on grade, rebar.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Too much over thinking.  The set up the OP is describing is that the pump turns on when the hot water is turned on in the master the master.  Once the water starts to warm up, the temperature bridge closes and pump shuts off.  The bridge closes before the water gets too warm.  I have a re-circulating hot water pump, and the water out of the cold faucet never feel hot or warm.  It is just not "cold".  So if you are looking for "cold" water out of the faucet, then a recirculating would be out of the question.

No- the water will NOT be hot coming out of the cold-side faucet, just not cold or cool.

If you think about it,  The water out of the cold side of the faucet will be the normal temp of the cold faucet water until the existing water on the hot water side has been expelled and heated water has reached the bridge.

If you want to spend the additional money for a separate return line to the pump to have cold water to drink, the builder will most likely accommodate you.

Comment: I appreciate your concise answer. And the fact of the mater is, we live in FL. 9x out of 10, the water coming out of the cold side is "warm" anyway.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually the recirculating system if using the cold will make the cold water hot! A new install just use a dedicated line for return.

Comment: Recirculating system may not be the correct term for this system. The therma-bridge which connects the hot water to the cold line and it is NOT a true loop back, shuts off when the water reaches a pre-set temperature.  It cuts off way before the water gets warm.  When the faucet is turn completely to cold, the water feels the same as any other faucet receiving cold water directly.

Comment: I do agree if the cost of a return line to the hot water is not a factor, and this is a new build, the separate return line to the hot is the best design.  Just stopping the notion that hot water is being pushed into the cold line.  It is the cold water in the hot water pipe that is being pushed into the cold line.  Once a preset temp in the bridge is reached. the flow is cut off.  If hot water is being pushed into the cold line, then the bridge thermocouple is defective.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't go into the cold - that is usually a hot loop back into the tank.

Another option is to have the hot water pipe sleeved with an electric water heater to keep the water at, or above, a given temperature.

You have to consider what priority you want - instant hot water with associated electricity use or a pump recirculating cooler water into the tank or into the cold.

Both will work.

Comment: If you're using a bridge valve wouldn't it run the warmed water into the cold side.  
Unless I use a dedicated return.

Comment: Is this designed by the builder or you?

Comment: The builder will do it however the plumber does it or unless I request otherwise.  They are suggesting a pump with a bridge valve at the furthest point.  So the warming water would flow into the cold side via the bridge valve.

I'm asking for them to do a dedicated return instead of a bridge valve so that while the pump is running it's only circulating hot water and not putting warm water down the cold supply to the sink.

Comment: "*recirculating cooler water into the tank*"  The question is about a tankless system.

Comment: @AlaskaMan well I would be starting with solar water heating anyway...

Comment: OP- It should not be a problem for the builder or plumber if you want to add the additional cost to have a dedicated line back to the hot water side.  The bridge design is used to not have to run a separate return line.

Comment: The hot water tank sleeved? Just install a small point of use electric tankless 1 second to hot water or the same as a recirculating system but no affect on the cold . A small 3-5 gallon tanked heater on the output of the tankless to run the recirculating loop , unless a dedicated return it will affect the cold but more efficient than trying to fire the huge tankless to keep pipes warm.